# What's wrong with timestamp here?

Tags: solidity, timestamp

```
if (externalId == bytes32(0x00)) {
    bytes memory buffer = new bytes(64);
    assembly {
        mstore(add(buffer, 0x20), escrowId)
        mstore(add(buffer, 0x40), timestamp)
                
    }
    externalId = keccak256(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Error says, builtin function timestamp must be called.

Answer (score 0):

In inside-assembly, you have to use `timestamp()` to read the `block.timestamp`.

```
if (externalId == bytes32(0x00)) {
    bytes memory buffer = new bytes(64);
    assembly {
        mstore(add(buffer, 0x20), escrowId)
        mstore(add(buffer, 0x40), timestamp())
                
    }
    externalId = keccak256(buffer);
}
```